# 30 Days Hath September

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, visual

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/)</sub>

---

[image]

... but what? Good luck on this [enigmatic-puzzle](/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle)!

Hints:

> Although it's not strictly part of the puzzle, the first sentence of this post may help you figure out where to start.

> This puzzle was released on **07-28-2022**.

> For the first step, you're looking for an emoji that is out of place. But for the next step, keep an eye out for any unusual details you might notice...

> The [cipher](/questions/tagged/cipher) tag is there for a reason -- this puzzle contains at least one!

*This puzzle is one of two remaining unsolved puzzles from the first Monthly Topic Challenge -- I hope it gets solved before it turns a year old. In light of that, I made changes to the numbers in the puzzle to hopefully make things clearer. Once again, good luck!*

Comment: The unusual things I notice are rot13(fbzr yrggref va gur gvgyr nobir gur tevq ner obyqrq, naq gung cuenfr vf fvzvyne gb n qngr sbezng. Nyfb gurer ner guvegl-bar qnlf va gur puneg.)

Comment: @Jarvis rot13(Trggvat pybfre -- jnag gb gnxr n penpx?)

Comment: Well, I think rot13(gurer vf n pbaarpgvba gb [guvf](https://xkcd.com/1944) kxpq pbzvp). I am still trying to find what I am looking for.

Comment: Almost a year now; how far is Daniel S's answer, and any hints to what we are missing?

Comment: @newQOpenWid Sorry for the late reply! I would say Daniel S's answer is about halfway to the solution, but is too eager to make a connection that actually isn't there. Keep in mind that this puzzle contains at least one cipher.

Comment: After almost a year of not looking at it, I've realized that the original puzzle's numbers don't make this puzzle very friendly to the solver at all. I've remedied that by changing the numbers and integrating the original third hint into the puzzle, but nothing that the solvers have already gotten to has been changed.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be related to

> xkcd comics 2041-2054 which are specifically:

> - Frontiers

> - Rolle’s Theorem

> - Boathouses and Houseboats

> - Sandboxing Cycle

> - Social Media Announcement

> - Trum-

> - Beverages

> - Curve-Fitting

> - Unfulfilling Toys

> - 6/6 Time

> - Bad Opinions

> - Stanislov Petrograd Day

All of which

> Are thematically linked to the emoji occurring on the date in September 2018 when they were published. The bold digits are readable as 1/9-1/10 /2018 (or other DMY formats). Following an observation from hexomino, there may be a link to [Fatal Crash Rate](https://xkcd.com/1993/) published on 14/5/18 and is comic 1993 so just fitting into the theme.

The anomaly would seem to be

> The final square labelled 18 which corresponds to the comic [Incoming Calls](https://xkcd.com/2053/) on the 1st October rather than a date in September. Thematically, wrong numbers are part of this strip. (Also possibly relevant is the comic [2018](https://xkcd.com/1935/)).

Comment: I feel like there's a bit more to it. 14-5-18 seems to be important and the leftover bold digits, in particular.

Comment: You're on the right track, but there's still a bit left to this puzzle! rot13(Gur bayl ceboyrz jvgu lbhe nafjre fb sne vf gur fgngrzrag "nyy bs juvpu"...)

Comment: Do you see rot13(gur eryngvba orgjrra gur svsgu pbzvp naq gur rzbwv? V qba'g frr.)

Comment: Might be a reference to rot13(gur Fynpx ybtb)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear on the pattern, but the smaller images are (in order)

> Eight-pointed star, Ophiuchus, motor boat, clockwise horizontal arrows (this one is possibly non-standard)

> Rainbow, trumpet, glass of milk, chart with upward trend

> Yoyo, 6, anger, bell

Edit:

> Hint 3 indicates that the final "18" is out of place, as every other Monday/Wednesday/Friday has a different emoji. I still haven't worked out any more specific rules for which number or emoji (if any) should appear for each day, though.

Comment: Well, yes — but how are the different images connected? I’ll add a hint.

Comment: Also, this might be better suited as a comment; it might be confused by other puzzlers as a partial or full solution.

Comment: I was hoping that the one difference I found would count as at least a partial solution. Now I'm looking at hint 3 and wondering rot13(ubj *bayl* bar guvat vf bhg bs cynpr).

Comment: rot13(V jvyy fnl gung guvf chmmyr unf zhygvcyr fgrcf gb vg. Lbh'ir nyernql cvpxrq hc n xrl qrgnvy va lbhe yngrfg rqvg, ohg abg gur xrl qrgnvy lbh zvtug guvax...)